# Sort dates of multiple json files with python

Tags: python, json, pandas, datetime

I got multiple json files and I am trying to sort them by date. I managed to print them out in 2 columns, DATE and TEXT, but the DATES are not in order.

When I try to mess around with datetime, nothing happens. I'm sure there's an easy solution, but I just can't find it.

```py
import os, json
import pandas as pd

path_to_json = 'MyPath'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]


jsons_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DATE', 'TEXT'])

for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
        json_text = json.load(json_file)

        DATE = json_text['DATE'] 
        TEXT = json_text['TEXT']

        jsons_data.loc[index] = [DATE, TEXT]

print(jsons_data)
```

Print dates in sorted order:

```
from datetime import datetime

def sort_data_by_datetime(jsons_data, field_name='DATE', datetime_format='%d.%m.%Y'):
    return sorted(jsons_data, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[field_name], datetime_format))

print(jsons_data)
```

Here is a snippet of my unordered result

```
          DATE                                               TEXT
0   19.08.2018  "Den Unmut der Sparer kann ich gut verstehen"\...
1   17.05.2019  „Selbstzufriedenheit ist sehr gefährlich“\n\nI...
2   25.08.2019  „Ich sehe keinen Grund zur Panik“\n\nInterview...
3   15.09.2018  "Bargeld ist gedruckte Freiheit"\n\nInterview ...
```

And of one of my json files

```
{"AUTHOR": "JoachimWuermeling", "PDF_URL": "-", "LOCAL_PDF_FILE": "-", "DATE": "02.10.2018", "TEXT": "Die Bundesbank digitalisiert die Bankenaufsicht\n\nInterview mit der Börsen-Zeitung\n\n\n\n02.10.2018\n\n|\nJoachim Wuermeling\n\n\nEN\n\nDas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jsons_data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(jsons_data['DATE'])
jsons_data = jsons_data.sort_values('DATE')
```

This might help.

Comment: Omg, sweet! Thanks, Danny that did the job!

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of Danny, this is the code that works, keeping the date structure and the index numbers intact:

```
jsons_data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(jsons_data['DATE'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
jsons_data = jsons_data.sort_values('DATE')
jsons_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```